# Manipulating data frame in R

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to mungle my data from the following data frame to the one following it where the values in column B and C are combined to column names for the values in D grouped by the values in A.

Below is a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(10)

fooDF <- data.frame(A = sample(1:4, 10, replace=TRUE), B = sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE), C= sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE), D = sample(1:4, 10, replace=TRUE))
fooDF[!duplicated(fooDF),]

   A B C D
1  4 c b 2
2  4 d a 2
3  2 a b 4
4  3 c a 1
5  4 a b 3
6  4 b a 2
7  1 b d 2
8  1 a d 4
9  2 b a 3
10 2 d c 2

newdata <- data.frame(A = 1:4)
for(i in 1:nrow(fooDF)){
    col_name <- paste(fooDF$B[i], fooDF$C[i], sep="")
    newdata[newdata$A == fooDF$A[i], col_name ] <- fooDF$D[i]


}
```

The format I am trying to get it in.

```
> newdata
  A cb da ab ca ba bd ad dc
1 1 NA NA NA NA NA  2  4 NA
2 2 NA NA  4 NA  3 NA NA  2
3 3 NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA
4 4  2  2  3 NA  2 NA NA NA
```

Right now I am doing it line by line but that is unfeasible for a large csv containing 5 million + lines. Is there a way to do it faster in R or python?

Comment: do the `B+C` values ever reoccur for a given `A` value? (i.e. would you have to sum multiple instances?)

Comment: Essentially just a tabulation isn't it - `xtabs(D ~ A + paste0(B,C), data=fooDF)` ?

Comment: @NathanDay B+C values do not reoccur for a given A value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`, this can be done with `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
fooDF %>%
     unite(BC, B, C, sep="")  %>%
     spread(BC, D)
#  A ab ad ba bd ca cb da dc
#1 1 NA  4 NA  2 NA NA NA NA
#2 2  4 NA  3 NA NA NA NA  2
#3 3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA
#4 4  3 NA  2 NA NA  2  2 NA
```

---

Or we can do this with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(fooDF), A~paste0(B,C), value.var = "D")
#    A ab ad ba bd ca cb da dc
#1: 1 NA  4 NA  2 NA NA NA NA
#2: 2  4 NA  3 NA NA NA NA  2
#3: 3 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA
#4: 4  3 NA  2 NA NA  2  2 NA
```

#### data

```
fooDF <- structure(list(A = c(4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
B = c("c", "d", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "d"), 
C = c("b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "d", "d", "a", "c"), 
D = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 3):

First paste columns B and C together (into column "z"):

```
fooDF$z = paste0(fooDF$B,fooDF$C)

   A B C D  z
1  3 d c 3 dc
2  1 b d 3 bd
3  1 a a 2 aa
4  2 d a 1 da
5  4 d c 1 dc
6  2 d b 2 db
7  4 b d 3 bd
8  2 c d 3 cd
9  1 a b 2 ab
10 4 a b 2 ab
```

Then I'll remove columns B and C

```
fooDF$B = NULL
fooDF$c = NULL
```

And last do a reshape from long to wide:

```
finalFooDF = reshape(fooDF, timevar = "z", direction = "wide",idvar = "A")

  A D.dc D.bd D.aa D.da D.db D.cd D.ab
1 3    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 1   NA    3    2   NA   NA   NA    2
4 2   NA   NA   NA    1    2    3   NA
5 4    1    3   NA   NA   NA   NA    2
```